# force g++ compiler to use a specific flag from x.cpp if the flag is available

Tags: c++, g++

Can I force g++ compiler to use a specific flag from x.cpp if the flag is available without a makefile?

I want that `g++ x.cpp` and `g++ -std=c++0x x.cpp` have the same result

Comment: What does "using a specific flag from x.cpp" mean?

Answer (score 3):

Kinda.

You can not set flags inside the `x.cpp`, but you can set **pragmas**.

[Here is a list](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html) of available pragmas from gcc online docs.